# -Asp.Net- how can I call a dialog from the controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, controller, dialog, modal-dialog

Ok I would like to know if it is possible, to be able to call a Dialog from the Controller and learn how to do it.

I am aware that this is something that isn't normally recommended, because the controller runs asynchronously in respect to the View, but in this case, I really need to do it, because it would simplify the code a lot and make my webpage run much less slow.

Since doing this, it isn't very different, to if I in the controller send the user to a different View, if certain conditions are met, with the data which the controller receives, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Create(List<Int> list)
{

//does stuff with the data in list and then if X happens:
 return View("VIEW RETURNED");

}
```

So what I want is that instead of this happening, and sending the user to a different View if certain conditions are met in the controller, I want this to make a Dialog appear in the View, something like this one:

https://miro.medium.com/max/2048/1*8vxEG0_9CBNboImHBhEP_w.png

The Dialog shows some information in html code and if I press "Cancel" something happens, and if I press accept something else it happens and the information is sent back to the Controller with some changes.

Is it really impossible to do this and manage the Dialogs from the controller? I've searched all over the internet and haven't found anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Dialog shows some information in html code and if I press "Cancel"
> something happens, and if I press accept something else it happens and
> the information is sent back to the Controller with some changes.
>
> Is it really impossible to do this and manage the Dialogs from the
> controller? I've searched all over the internet and haven't found
> anything about it.

From your description, you want to use a popup dialog to make a condition (cancel and delete), if the user selects one of them, it should do something in the controller. If that is the case, you could use the [Bootstrap Modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp) to show the dialog, and use JQuery Ajax to call the action method and do something, code as below:

Index.cshtml: add two buttons in the Bootstrap Modal, and use JQuery to capture the button click event, then using JQuery ajax to call the action method and do something in the Ajax success function.

```
<!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
<button id="btnOpenModal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalcontent">
            
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, delete it</button>
                @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>*@
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#btnOpenModal").click(function () {
                // call the action method, in the success function add the return data in the Modal content.
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: "/Home/GetViewContent",  //remember change the controller to your owns.  
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data)
                        $('#modalcontent').html(data);
                    }, 
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
            //Popup Modal's Cancel button click
            $("#myModal").on("click", ".btn-default", function () {
                //since the button element using the data-dismiss attribute, there is no need to close the Modal via jquery.
                // code. using jquery ajax do something
                alert("Cancel button click");
            });
            //Popup Modal's  delete button click
            $("#myModal").on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
                // code
                alert("Delete button click");

                //using the following code to close the popup modal.                
                $('#myModal').modal('hide') //or  $("#myModal").modal('toggle');

                //using JQuery Ajax to call the action method.
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

HomeController.cs:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult GetViewContent()
    {
        return Ok("You'll lose all responses data. Are you sure you want to delete them?");
    }
```

Using the default _Layout.cshtml

[image]

[Note] In Above Asp.net Core MVC application, I'm using the default template/layout and it already uses the Bootstrap reference (JS+CSS), if you are not using the default template/layout, you should add the related BootStrap and JQuery reference.

The screenshot as below:

[image]

**Update**:

To use JQuery ajax to call the action method which used the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute, we should add the RequestVerificationToken in the request header. Please check the following code:

Add the following code in the Index.cshtml:

```
    @model WebApplication.Models.Book

    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="BookId" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="BookId" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="BookId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="BookName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="BookName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="BookName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div> 
    </form>
```

And, add the following Create button in the Modal footer

```
 <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary btncreate" data-dismiss="modal">Create</button>
```

Book.cs:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
}
```

Create action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Book book)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var data = book;

            return Ok("Insert Success");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Then, in the create button click event, create a JS object and send it to action method:

```
        //Popup Modal's Create button click
        $("#myModal").on("click", ".btncreate", function () { 
            //using JQuery Ajax to call the action method.
            var book = {};
            book.BookName = $("#BookName").val();
            book.BookId = $("#BookId").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Create",
                type: "POST",
                data: book, 
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader(
                        "RequestVerificationToken",
                        $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val());
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure I'm not applying the code wrong, which are the BootStrap and JQuery references?? I'm not using the default template/layout.

Comment: Please check [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBNmH.png), when we create a .net core application using the MVC template, it has installed the JQuery and BootStrap client library, you can find them from the `wwwroot` folder. And in the _Layout.cshtml page, we can see it already add the JQuery and BootStrap JS and CSS references.So, in the main page, if you are using the `_Layout.cshtml`, there is no need to add JQuery and Bootstrap references again. If you are not using the _Layout.cshtml page in the main page, you have to add the JQuery and Bootstrap reference before the JS scripts.

Comment: Hii! if you're still there, I'm having trouble sending information to the method GetViewContent(), now my controller has something like: "
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult GetViewContent(CcViewModel data)
        { " but this isn't receiving the information from the Model, something that "<div class = "form-group">
                         <input type = "submit" value = "CREATE" class = "btn btn-primary" />" does, which leads to the Create method; What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ok what is happening is that the model is not being sent to the controller method, so the model is not binding. 

The way which I receive the Model in the Create Method is as follows:
===
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CcViewModel data)
        {}
===
And my buttons are inside a:
===
<form asp-action="Create"></form>=== ; So, how do I bind the model into the method GetViewContent()?

Comment: Hi @MarcosFuente, Please check the Update in the above reply. To use JQuery Ajax to call the action method which used the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute, we should add the RequestVerificationToken in the request header. Then, create a JS object and populate the value, after that send to the action method.

Comment: Hi again! @Zhi Lv I just need to solve a final problem so the code works as I want, You will see in my View I have a list of CheckBoxes, but I am having problems to sent the values of the Checkboxes to the Method with the Script, I tried this and it didn't work: https://justpaste.it/63tjh I didn't know that it wasn't so simple to send the group of Checkboxes with the Script, can you help me with it? I don't know if it makes any difference but I'm using Asp Net Core 5.0.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed the problem, thank you really =) !!! ( $.each($("input[name='selectedC']:checked"), function () {
               valuesDus.push($(this).val());
           });   )